# Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. While installing cordova-plugin-geofence plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

C:\My App\test>ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence --save
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>    {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- minimist@1.2.0
- xml2js@0.4.19
  updated 2 packages in 33.453s

Installing "cordova-plugin-geofence" for android

Installing "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" for android

Android Studio project detected

Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android

**Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.0.0, failed
 version requirement:
      <6.3.0**

Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Installing "es6-promise-plugin" for android

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Adding cordova-plugin-geofence to package.json

Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-geofence" to config.xml

Ionic Versions Info :

cli packages: (C:\Users\Shadab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.9.4
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Shadab\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the "cordova platforms" command to see what version of android you have. In my case I was using 6.2.3. What I did is I updated my android version using the "cordova platform update android@6.3.0"command. After that add the plugins again and you should be good to go.